# How to set the value attribute of a hidden field when runat=server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

How can i set the value of a hiddenfield when set `runat= server`,using javascript?

E.g `document.getElementById("<%=hiddenid.ClientID%>").value ="45"`. `Value` attribute is not accessible here. How can i set that?

Comment: Yes, I want to set the hidden field value through javascript and use it within the html tag to bind a select control.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `single quote '` `instead double "`

```
document.getElementById('<%=hiddenid.ClientID%>').value = '45';
```

Answer (score 0):

Control's ClientID becomes set/available in the PreRender event handler, so you can use that to pass the ID to the client-side.

Additionally you can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) to Static to force the ID to never change.

Comment: Is that possible with an html hidden control?

Comment: Sure, it derives from HtmlControl class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputhidden%28v=VS.100%29.aspx;

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but make sure the element actually exists when you try to get it by ID. In other words, make sure that your javascript is executed after the element is created by the browser.